# Adding other columns into a join with a group by

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, oracle11g

In Oracle 11g Express, I have the following query:

```
select t1.product_name, SUM(t1.product_cost_per_month)
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 on (t1.product_name = t2.product_name)
WHERE t2.date > sysdate
GROUP BY t1.product_name
```

This works, it returns the sum of the cost of products per month, group by product after a certain date (I just use sysdate here as an example).

However, I would like to display some additional description about each product, i.e the vendor. So I use this code:

```
select t1.product_name, SUM(t1.product_cost_per_month), t2.vendor
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.product_name = t2.product_name)
WHERE t2.date > sysdate
GROUP BY t1.product_name
```

This doesn't work because all variables need to have an aggregation function applied to them to use "Group by", but an aggregation function for something like "vendor" seems meaningless... So is there a way to do this?

I am probably going to write a short pl/sql routine to solve, but I am wondering if there is a purely SQL way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendor should also be included in the GROUP BY clause.

```
GROUP BY t1.product_name, t2.vendor
```

Another technique to achieve what you're doing would be a nested query:

```
SELECT t1.product_name,
    (
        select sum(product_cost_per_month) 
         from table2 t2 
         where 
            t1.product_name = t2.product_name 
            and t2.date > sysdate
    ) as total_product_cost,
    t1.another_field,
    t1.another_field2,
    t1.another_field3
FROM table1
```

(Apologies for any errors, I didn't test this but this should give you the gist of it)

Comment: Thanks this does work... However (and now this is more of a theoretical question): Perhaps another bit of description I would want to include is the total purchase cost. Does it make sense to "group by" the total purchase cost of something?

Comment: In that case wouldn't it be an aggregate? `SUM(purchase_cost)` or something along those lines?

Comment: Excellent, I am just starting to learn nested queries, but that is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I can't not enough reputation... :(  (only two more points to go)